# How to make image attatchment button

Tags: php, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP4hq.png)how to make an attachment activity... Means i have to create an activity in which i have to give a edit text box for user suggestion and an image button for adding an image if necessary related to his suggestion.. and then send this data to server...

i have created an edit text and send data to web server.. but i have no idea about image upload..

**My MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText ed1;
Button submit;
Button cancel;
Button btnselectphoto; 
String toBeSent;
String imagePath=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.submit) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (ed1.getText().toString().length() < 1) {

        // out of range
        Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {
        toBeSent = ed1.getText().toString();

        new MyAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, toBeSent,imagePath).execute();
    }

}

    else if (v.getId()==R.id.cancel) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "thank you for comming", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    }

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Context context;
    private String data;
    private InputStream is;
    private String response;
    private String imagePath;

    public MyAsyncTask(Context context, String data,String imagePath) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.imagePath=imagePath;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("dataToBeSent", data));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_path",imagePath));

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/municipal/DummyTestFolder/insertQuery.php");// //URL will Come Here


            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent= new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8);
            httpPost.setEntity(ent);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            int statusCode=httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.e("Status Code<><><>", ""+statusCode);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            response = sb.toString();
            Log.v("Login webservice response", "Login response == "
                    + response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if((response!=null)){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Uploaded Comment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ed1.setText("");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for Image uploading

```
public class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String data = Utils.PROFILE_UPLOAD_URL;
    String text = "";
    String fileName = sourceFile.substring(sourceFile.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    ProgressDialog pd;
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(ProfileDetails.this, R.style.MyTheme);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Large);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(Utils.PROFILE_UPLOAD_URL);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            text = sb.toString();
            Log.i("RES", text.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        String res = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(text);
            res = jobj.getString("status_txt");
            if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                String responce = jobj.getJSONObject("data").getString("thumb_url");
                editor.putString(Utils.THUMB_URL, responce);
                editor.commit();
                Log.i("RESPONCE123", responce);
                pd.dismiss();
            } else {
            }
        } catch (JSONException jerror) {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i want image click on a button which i have created in main activity.. inside edit text just like image attatchment in gmail... i dont want to open another window or activity for image capture.. my image button is on side bottom corner of a edit text.. i want to attatch image with edit text and image will sent to server with my text on edit text when i click send button...